# CAShapeLayer resolution

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

please help to understand the issue regarding the layers and their resolution. I draw cubes each of which consists of three layers ( background, border and letter) after rotation of the edge lines look stepped

[screen shot of cubes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uVoZ.png)

```
let backLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    backLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    backLayer.bounds = backBounds
    backLayer.backgroundColor = color
    backLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    backLayer.position = position
    backLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    backLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowWidth, height: shadowWidth)
    backLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    backLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    backLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    let subPosition = CGPoint(x: backLayer.bounds.height / 2  + dipper, y: backLayer.bounds.height / 2)


    // Border Layer
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0  , y: 0.0, width: backLayer.bounds.width - dipper, height: backLayer.bounds.height)
    borderLayer.position = subPosition
    borderLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    borderLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    borderLayer.borderColor = color
    borderLayer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    borderLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    borderLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    borderLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    borderLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale



    // char layer
    let charLayer = CATextLayer()
    charLayer.bounds = borderLayer.bounds
    charLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    charLayer.position = subPosition
    charLayer.string = NSString(UTF8String: char)
    charLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    charLayer.wrapped = true
    charLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    charLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowWidth / 3, height: shadowWidth / 3)
    charLayer.shadowRadius = 2
    charLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    charLayer.truncationMode = kCATruncationMiddle
    charLayer.font = "BookmanOldStyle-Bold"
    charLayer.fontSize = height / 1.4
    charLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Comment: Is it possible to include also the code for rotation? Meanwhile, [you could try setting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/allowsEdgeAntialiasing) `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` & `edgeAntialiasingMask` on the layers...

Comment: @Alladinian code for rotation very simple `container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)` `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` really work, Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad that helped you. I have also posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try enabling the edge antialiasing on the layers. Something like this:

```
layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
```

and in case you want antialiasing on specific edges (in this example only left & right):

```
layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = [.LayerLeftEdge, .LayerRightEdge]
```

Finally, it is worth noting that you can set this globally if you like in your info.plist.

The key is `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing`, but be careful cause according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW5) "*it can have a noticeable impact on performance*"